# Execution times for decryption aren't uniform, half are around 0ms other half around 12ms, what's the reason? (NodeJS)

Tags: python, node.js, encryption, cryptography, performance-testing

So what Im doing is --

I am calling a command like `node filepath.js encryptedInput` from a python script, 1000 times using `subprocess.run`. The node script is using the `crypto` library. NodeJS code is like this:

```
Start timer using process.hrtime
read encryptedInput from command line argument
use crypto to decrypt using encryption algorithm/cipher
console log decrypted (convert hex to utf8)
console log time taken
```

and I get the decrypted output like

```
This is the decrypted text
12.23ms
```

so all of this works great. Python then takes the `12.23` from the output and stores in array, and the time output is produced and stored in an array with 1000 entries and plotted.

NOW, my issue is.....I have the exact same code in two NodeJS scripts, except the encryption algorithm is different (but using the same libraries and records time the same way)

The script using the AES cipher returns time consistent around 11-12ms 1000 times

But, the script using ChaCha20 cipher returns half of the 1000 trial time data at around 0.002 or something ms (near zero) and other half around 11ms....but for this script if I don't convert the hex output to utf8 then the time gets consistent around 12ms or so, although the AES script is using the same library for decryption and returns utf8 and the times are consistent

My question is....why is the ChaCha20 script returning weird data, although it uses the same library and same code (Except one line, where in the algorithm name section it is chacha20 instead of aes and it uses the appropiate key size) and why is the AES one consistent?

Encryption decryption works properly because the plaintext retrieved is accurate

Any idea what to do? I am testing the time taken to get readable text data from the script, so I guess converting to utf8 readable text is part of the process. Thanks for reading this far :)

Comment: If you are calling 1000 nodejs from command-line then 99% of the measured time will be the start-up time of node.js, not execution time of your code. Instead write JavaScript code that performs 2 * 100000 cryptographic operations. The first 100000 ignore (give node.js time to set-up) the latter 100000 measure from within node.js.

Comment: What I want to measure basically is, how long it takes for the script to load, read encrypted input, decrypt, and return readable text., 1000 times to get avg. So I guess I want to measure both how the algorithm performs and how much time the script takes overall. But the issue is, even using the same library, chacha20 is getting half the times near 0 and other half is near 11ms so avg is like 5-6ms, but when I don't convert the decrypted text to utf8 this issue goes away. Altough AES converts the decrypted text to utf8 and its times are very consistent, very few outliers.

Comment: Most recent CPUs have special commands for AES so it is implemented in hardware. For ChaCha20 everything has to be implemented in software. May be the code is implemented in a native library which has to be loaded which depending on your OS can kick in anti-virus check and something like that. And that you are using the same library is irrelevant, the library can implement both algorithms totally different internally.

Comment: Hmmm....if I test this on a raspberry pi would I get more neutral results? or is there a way to test without background processes? I ran it on ubuntu booted from a usb stick and the results were faster, but the pattern was similar where half the execution times for chacha20 were near zero and other half were normal, but aes stayed consistent.